# Camfind API issue in PHP

Tags: php, curl

For anyone familiar with the Camfind API, I've got a bit of a stumper today Implementing the API in PHP. I've followed the instructions as best I could, and I'm getting the proper token back for my first call. I'm then appending the token to the URL, removing the form data, and keeping the json header, as well as the header with my key. Whatever I try, however, returns: array(1) { ["status"]=> string(13) "not completed" }

Here's my code:

```
<?php
///////////////////////////////////
// FIRST REQUEST
///////////////////////////////////

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests';
$fields = array(
    "image_request[altitude]" => "27.912109375",
    "image_request[language]" => "en",
    "image_request[latitude]" => "35.8714220766008",
    "image_request[locale]" => "en_US",
    "image_request[longitude]" => "14.3583203002251",
    "image_request[remote_image_url]" => "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
);
$headers = array(
    'X-Mashape-Key: I-put-my-real-key-here',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: application/json'
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, true);



///////////////////////////////////
// SECOND REQUEST
///////////////////////////////////

//set POST variables
$url = "https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_responses/" . $result['token'];
echo $url;

$headers = array(
    'X-Mashape-Key: I-put-my-real-key-here',
    'Accept: application/json'
);



//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Camfind support just got back to me, and made the following suggestion "Hi, it takes around 10-15 seconds for the image recognition to occur. Build in a loop with a delay before making the second call with the token, or try calling again and use a timer to re-call if not completed is still returned until it changes status to completed."

With this advice, I've updated my code as follows:

I added:

```
$start = microtime(true);
```

To the top of my file. I then wrapped my second curl call like so:

```
do {


    //set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 30);

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

} while((number_format((microtime(true) - $start), 2) < 20) && $result['status'] == 'not completed');
```

This is the solution, and the search now executes correctly.